# AWS S3 Transfer Between Accounts Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy data in a bucket in one account, in which I have access to an IAM but not admin, to a bucket in another account, in which I am an admin, and failing. I can't even `ls` the source bucket.

I've followed the directions from AWS and various sources online to give myself list/read/get permissions on the source bucket, with no success. I can provide the details (e.g., the bucket policy json), but it is what is in the AWS docs and other places. What I've done works between two accounts I have admin access to.

This is "multi-region", in the sense that I'm in the US (mainly `us-west-2`) but the bucket is in `eu-central-1`. I am specifying the region in the aws cli, and set up a destination bucket in `eu-central-1`, but can't even list anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this couple of times with my AWS accounts. I am guessing you have setup cross account Access to your S3 bucket, but just double check, here is what I do for granting an S3 bucket cross account access.

Account (A):
  S3 bucket (testbucket)

Account (B):
  IAM User (testuser) needs access to the S3 bucket testbucket in Account (A)

Here are things that need to happen:

Create a bucket policy on testbucket (A) to grant read/list etc access to to your test bucket.
example:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "BUCKETPOLICY",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowS3ReadObject28",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::900000000:user/testuser"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

2. Create an IAM policy on testuser that also grants read, write, list etc access to the bucket.

Comment: The Bucket Policy in Account A is sufficient to grant access. There is no need to create a policy on the user in Account B -- in fact, Account B cannot grant permission for anything in Account A anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your situation is:

- **Account A:** Bucket A and User A (with limited access rights)
- **Account B:** Bucket B and User B (with admin rights)

You can either **push** the data from Account A to Bucket B, or you can **pull** the data from Bucket A using Account B.

**Pushing from Account A to Bucket B**

Let's assume User A has access to Bucket A. All that's needed is to give User A permission to write to Bucket B. This can be done with a **bucket policy on Bucket B**:

```
{
  "Id": "PolicyB",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GrantAccessToUserA",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-B",
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-B/*"
      ],
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-A:user/USER-A"
    }
  ]
}
```

This grants *all* s3 permissions to User A on Bucket B. That's excessive, but presumably this is only temporary.

User A would then copy the files from Bucket A to Bucket B. For example:

```
aws s3 sync s3://BUCKET-A s3://BUCKET-B \
  --acl bucket-owner-full-control \
  --source-region SOURCE-REGION \
  --region DESTINATION-REGION
```

**Important:** When copying the files, be sure to use the Access Control List that grants `bucket-owner-full-control`. This means that the files become *owned* by the owner of Bucket B. If you don't do this, the files are still owned by User A and can't be deleted by User B, even with admin rights!

**Pulling from Bucket A using Account B**

To do this, User B must be granted access to Bucket A. You will need enough access rights in Account A to add a **bucket policy on Bucket A**:

```
{
  "Id": "PolicyA",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GrantAccessToUserB",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-A",
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-A/*"
      ],
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-B:user/USER-B"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, User B can copy the files across:

```
aws s3 sync s3://BUCKET-A s3://BUCKET-B \
  --source-region SOURCE-REGION \
  --region DESTINATION-REGION
```

(You might need to grant some more access rights, I didn't test the above policy.)

The fact that buckets are in different regions does not impact the permissions, but it does impact *where* you send the command. The command is sent to the destination region, which then pulls from the source region.

See: [AWS CLI `s3 sync` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)