# Sign S3 request using AWS EC2 instance' account

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I've succesfully used below bash code to sign requests to S3 using a access key pair, without having to use the aws cli:

```
aws_access_key_id="[key id]"
aws_secret_access_key="[secret access key]"
bucket='somebucket'
key='/path/To/Key'

resource="/${bucket}${key}"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="GET\n\n\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${aws_secret_access_key} -binary | base64`
/usr/bin/curl --progress-bar -k -sb \
  -H "GET ${key}" \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${aws_access_key_id}:${signature}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com${key} 2>&1
```

This works if you have an access key pair. What if you want to sign the request based on generic credentials of the current EC2 instance AWS account? So this request is fired from one AWS account (1), the S3 bucket is in another account (2). Account-1 is granted access to Account-2' S3 bucket based on the account ARN.

Can we still (relatively easily) achieve this without having to use aws-cli?

Comment: this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials

Comment: Similar to [AWS S3 Transfer Between Accounts Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718983/174777). Basically, the Bucket in Account-2 needs to permit access to the Account-1 entity that is generating the STS credentials.